# Issue with asp:ContentPlaceHolder and code blocks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

When a content placeholder contains any code blocks it reports that the control collection is empty.

For instance:

*MasterPage.aspx*

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content1" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content2" runat="server" />

<div>Content1: <%= Content1.Controls.Count %></div>
<div>Content2: <%= Content2.Controls.Count %></div>
```

*APage.aspx*

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content1" runat="server">
    Plain text content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content2" runat="server">
    <%= "Code block content." %>
</asp:Content>
```

This will render the following:

> Plain text content. Code block content.
>
> Content1: 1
>
> Content2: 0

Why is the master page's ContentPlaceHolder.Controls collection empty?

I want to check whether the ContentPlaceHolder has been populated (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964271)) but can't if it contains any `<%=` blocks.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on previous question - will check this out later once home from the office.. This one intrigues me! (+1 from me!) Will update later :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As promised, I said I would take a look. Sorry I never uploaded last night, long day and needed to hit the hay!

So, I was checking out the `ContentPlaceHolder.Controls` collection differences between how they are populated. I noticed that when the code block is used, it flips to read only. At any other point, it will simply be empty or populated.

I therefore decided to throw in an extension method to check it for us:

#### ContentPlaceHolderExtensions.cs

```
public static class ContentPlaceHolderExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsControlsOrCodeBlock(this ContentPlaceHolder placeHolder)
    {
        if (placeHolder.Controls.Count > 0)
             return true;
        
        return placeHolder.Controls.IsReadOnly;
    }
}
```

And then check this in the master page:

#### Site.Master

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content1" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content2" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content3" runat="server" />

<div>Content1: <%= Content1.Controls.Count %></div>
<div>Content2: <%= Content2.Controls.Count %></div>
<div>Content3: <%= Content3.Controls.Count %></div>

<div>Content1 (Ex. Meth.): <%= Content1.ContainsControlsOrCodeBlock() %></div>
<div>Content2 (Ex. Meth.): <%= Content2.ContainsControlsOrCodeBlock() %></div>
<div>Content3 (Ex. Meth.): <%= Content3.ContainsControlsOrCodeBlock() %></div>
```

As proof-of-concept, I then added a content page:

#### Index.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content1" runat="server">
Plain Text Content
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content2" runat="server">
<%= "Code block content" %>
</asp:Content>
```

And all rendered as expected (I believe)..

TBH, while it is not *perfect*.. I don't think we can get much more elegance in this situation. I am not sure how other control collections are set up in these different scenarios, so I only bolted on to the ContentPlaceHolder control.. Other templated controls may or may not work the same.

Thoughts?

You can download the project from [here](http://code.google.com/p/robcthegeek/source/browse/#svn/trunk/stackoverflow/964724):

http://code.google.com/p/robcthegeek/source/browse/#svn/trunk/stackoverflow/964724

Comment: Cheers (+1 and acc) that works a treat. I made one tweak - an additional check for a single LiteralControl containing only whitespace.

Comment: Good call, I was thinking of adding that myself :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Too much for a comment, here's the full code that I finally got working (adapted from @Rob Cooper's answer):

```
public static bool HasContent( this ContentPlaceHolder placeHolder )
{
    if ( placeHolder.Controls.Count > 0 )
    {
        LiteralControl textBlock;
        ContentPlaceHolder subContent;

        foreach ( var ctrl in placeHolder.Controls )
            if ( (textBlock = ctrl as LiteralControl) != null )
            {   //lit ctrls will hold any blocks of text
                if ( textBlock.Text != null && textBlock.Text.Trim() != "" )
                    return true;
            }
            else if ( (subContent = ctrl as ContentPlaceHolder) != null )
            {   //sub content controls should call this recursively
                if ( subContent.HasContent() )
                    return true;
            }
            else return true;   //any other control counts as content

        //controls found, but all are empty
        return false;
    }

    //if any code blocks are used the render mode will be different and no controls will
    //be in the collection, however it will be read only
    return placeHolder.Controls.IsReadOnly;
}
```

This includes two extra checks - firstly for empty literal controls (which occur if the page includes the `<asp:Content` tags with any whitespace between them) and then for sub-ContentPlaceHolder which will occur for any nested master pages.

Answer (score 2):

The controls collection is empty because when <%= %> script tags are present, literal controls are not added to the control tree. However, server controls will still get added. So:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content2" Runat="Server">
     <%= "Code block content." %>
     <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTest" />
</asp:Content>

<div>Content2: <%= Content2.Controls.Count %></div>
```

will return

> Content 2: 1

Rick Strahl has a great article [that explains this behavior](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0609061&page=3):

> To make code like this work, ASP.NET
>   needs to override the rendering of the
>   particular container in which any
>   script code is hosted. It does this by
>   using SetRenderMethodDelegate on the
>   container and creating a custom
>   rendering method ...
>
> Rather than building up the control
>   tree literal controls, ASP.NET only
>   adds server controls to the control
>   tree when <% %> tags are present for a
>   container. To handle the literal
>   content and the script markup, ASP.NET
>   generates a custom rendering method.
>   This method then explicitly writes out
>   any static HTML content and any script
>   expressions using an HTML TextWriter.
>   Any script code (<% %>) is generated
>   as raw code of the method itself.

Unfortunately I can't think of any elegant solution to this conundrum.

Comment: Nice explanation. That's a pain for MVC content though - I don't want to clutter <% %> content with <asp:Controls> just so that the Master page can see that the content panel has been used. There has to be some way round this.